# Passing props and mapping data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a project that requires me to pass data to two functional components.

My axios call to the API seems to work, as well as setting the state with hooks, but I keep receiving these two errors:

1. Error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object` I tried checking if the array is empty but that didn't seem to solve the problem
2. `summaryMetrics` is not defined - This I don't understand because `summartMetrics` is defined. Could it be that the elements are being displayed before the data is fetched ?

Here are the files in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-shape-ydzj9?file=/src/Summary.js)
Included the API's so people can see the structure of how the JSON is being returned.
Im not sure if I'm passing and mapping the data correctly.

[image]

[image]

Here are the files in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-shape-ydzj9?file=/src/Summary.js)

Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Since your state has this form :

```
const [summary, setSummaryData] = useState({
  summaryMetrics: null,
  platformsData: null
});
```

...you should access your state like this :

```
<SummaryMetrics
  uniqueSocialMediaPost={summary.summaryMetrics[0]["uniqueSocialMediaPost"]}
  positiveScore={summary.summaryMetrics[0]["positiveScore"]}
  riskScore={summary.summaryMetrics[0]["riskScore"]}
/>

[...]
```

Note the "**summary.**" before "**summaryMetrics**" :

```
summary.summaryMetrics[0]["uniqueSocialMediaPost"]
```

Fixed Fixed Code Sandbox <s>(other things seems to go wrong though, white screen, but syntax error is fixed)</s> :

[image: Edit keen-goldwasser-fhj8j]

Previous errors were :

- mocky.io serves content over HTTP, Code Sandbox over HTTPS so mixed content issue : Chrome does not allow this kind of mix in protocols, fixed by using HTTPS protocol to grab infos from mocky.io,
- no unique keys for SummaryByPlatform component in map function

Chrome dev tools is your friend when nothing happens as expected :).

By the way you could just

```
summary.summaryMetrics.map(s => <SummaryByPlatform summaryMetrics={s} />)
```

...instead of gettings keys, and you could simply pass whole summaryMetrics object to SummaryByPlatform and have only one props. But that's another subject.

Good luck with it.

Comment: the error still states `summaryMetrics` is not defined in the sandbox

Comment: It says "Cannot read property '0' of null" on summary.summaryMetrics because summary.summaryMetrics is null, but it does not say that summaryMetrics is undefined anymore. See other answers on why this variable is null (basically : it is initialized as null, and you are trying to read it before calling useState to set it). Updated my sandbox to add a null check to prevent this new error, now there is a network error on a mocky.io request.

Comment: I updated the default state for `summaryMetrics` to be `"0"`, it displays 0, but its never updated after the API request.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not waiting for summaryMetrics to load. It's trying to read the array before it's been fetched.

What I would do, is put the render inside a function and conditionally load it once the data is available.

So your Summary.js file would look like this:

```
  const renderSummaryMetrics = () => 
    summary && 
    summary.summaryMetrics && (
    <div>
      <SummaryMetrics
        uniqueSocialMediaPost={summary.summaryMetrics[0]["uniqueSocialMediaPost"]}
        positiveScore={summary.summaryMetrics[0]["positiveScore"]}
        riskScore={summary.summaryMetrics[0]["riskScore"]}
      />
      {Object.keys(summary.summaryMetrics) &&
      Object.keys(summary.summaryMetrics).length > 0
        ? Object.keys(summary.summaryMetrics).map(keyName => (
            <SummaryByPlatform
              platform={keyName}
              mean_sentiment={summary.summaryMetrics[keyName].mean_sentiment}
              post_count={summary.summaryMetrics[keyName].post_count}
              positive_posts={summary.summaryMetrics[keyName].positive_posts}
              negative_posts={summary.summaryMetrics[keyName].negative_posts}
            />
          ))
        : null}
    </div>);

    return renderSummaryMetrics();
```

Comment: If  the `Summary.js` is changed to what you suggest, where would the `useEffect` calls go?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

1. `summaryMetrics` is indeed not defined. It was actually defined as `summary.summaryMetrics`.
2. `summary.summaryMetrics[0][...]` will cause another "undefined error", because it was defined with default value of `null`.

### Explanation for Problem 1:

No further explanation needed.

### Explanation for Problem 2:

`useEffect` in React functional component will only be run *after* the component is being rendered.

This means that when you execute `summary.summaryMetrics[0][...]`, `summary.summaryMetrics` is actually `null` because you defined it as the default value. Therefore, the steps behind will generate another error because `null[0]` is not possible.

What you need to do is to check whether each object properties down the tree is actually a valid object before you call the property. Otherwise, the error will happen down the property tree.

I can't show you how to correct your code, because I would need to change a big part of you code. What you can try is to mainly check the presence of values of `summary.summaryMetrics` first, before calling it's children properties.